# UIVisualEffect blurView works on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have been trying to get a UIVisualEffectView to work, and it works in the simulator, but not when I use it on my iPhone. I am not using SpriteKit or anything else that the internet has told me doesn't work, so this is utterly confusing.

I use the following code to add a translucent strip to the top of my view controller:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleRegular];

UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

[blurEffectView setAlpha:1];

blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;

[blurEffectView setFrame: CGRectMake(blurEffectView.frame.origin.x,
                                     blurEffectView.frame.origin.y,
                                     blurEffectView.frame.size.width,
                                     64)];

[self.view insertSubview:blurEffectView atIndex:1];
```

**iPhone**
**[image: iPhone]**

**Simulator**
**[image: Simulator]**

Comment: Why did you insert your subview at index 1? not 0? Your blurview might be covered by some other view.

Comment: @antonio081014 No, it was to not obscure the little logos in the top left and right corners

Answer (score 0):

NSLog the frame value to make sure it is placed right in the view. Seems like the view is there but not framed correctly.

Comment: Please look at the pictures that I linked to. It is showing up fine in the simulator. I would like it to do the same on the phone and I have no clue as to why the same code would run differently on the actual device than on the simulator. Thanks

Comment: I understand and I would expect the same. But for diagnosis the issue, I would have checked that to make sure frame is not messed up on device.

Comment: @TZM did you find the issue?

Comment: I added
    NSLog(@"Frame: \nx: %f\ny: %f\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f\n", blurEffectView.frame.origin.x, blurEffectView.frame.origin.y, blurEffectView.frame.size.width, blurEffectView.frame.size.height);
to my code, and it gave me values of (0, 0, 375, 64), as expected, but still did not show up. I do not have "reduces transparency" enabled either.